# Values not getting printed outside a for loop

Tags: servlets

in my program  a simple shopping application for my lab exercise, i just calculated the price of items inside a for loop but when i try to print it outside it is not getting printed...pls give me some  suggestion.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            String selection = request.getParameter("a" + i);

            if (selection.equals("l")) {

                price = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b" + i));
                total = total + price;

                out.println("<h3>You have purchased the item:<br>Price is:</h3>" + price);
            }
        }
        out.println("THE TOTAL IS"+total);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String selection = request.getParameter("a" + i);
 //Here print the selection there is the problem
 if (selection.equals("l")) ///Here alway it is false thats why you are getting this.
 {
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

It gets not printed because its out of scope. Your `total`
variable only lives within the loop.

http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: i have took the following lines and pasted outside of the try block and its working the total value is getting printed... out.println("THE TOTAL IS"+total);out.println("</body>"); out.println("</html>"); But there is another problem here whenever i skip a check box (example first and the last checkbox) the for loop is printing only the first value..it is not checking the last value....can u give some suggestion..